# Find and remove div with class containing &nbsp;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to remove any "empty" divs containing the html `&nbsp;`. First I need to find them and remove the `&nbsp;` then, remove the containing div.

The class is .ProductDetailsGrid.prodAccordionContent .Label for the div to be removed, and the `&nbsp;` should be found in 
.productHighlights .Value class

This works to remove all "`&nbsp;`" from the page, but I only want to delete from a certain class div. (.productHighlights .Value)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').each(function(){
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&nbsp;/gi,''));
    });
});
```

This is what I am trying, but it's not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ProductDetailsGrid.prodAccordionContent .Label ').each(function(){
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&nbsp;/gi,''));
    });
});
if ($('.productHighlights .Value').is(':empty')) { 
    $('.ProductDetailsGrid.prodAccordionContent .Label').remove();
}
```

Please help, something's not right. Here's the page too, I'm trying to remove the last checkmark that is empty under product highlights.

https://www.motionmedia.com/pny-nvidia-quadro-m6000-12gb-gddr5-pcie-30-gpu/

Comment: Shouldn't that be done serverside? There must be some misentry in the CMS / database ... ? !

Comment: why are you removing the whitespace THEN removing the div? why not just remove the div? I don't quite understand

Comment: Both good points. Server side can't be done for reasons I'm not going into here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get rid of empty value check marks:

```
$('.productHighlights  .DetailRow .Value').each(function(k,v) {
        var value = $($('.productHighlights  .DetailRow .Value')[k]).text();
    if(value.trim() == '') {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach if you just need to remove the last checkmark that is empty under product highlights. Hope this helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".ProductDetailsGrid.prodAccordionContent").find(".DetailRow:last-child").removeClass("DetailRow");
});
```

```css
.DetailRow{
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ProductDetailsGrid prodAccordionContent">
    <div class="DetailRow">Text1</div>
    <div class="DetailRow">Text2</div>
    <div class="DetailRow">Text3</div>
    <div class="DetailRow">Text4</div>
</div>
```